# How to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit in code

Tags: c, math

First code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int Celsius;
    
    printf("temperature in Celsius?\n");
    scanf("%d", &Celsius);
    
    float Fahrenheit = (Celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
    
    printf("temperature in Fahrenheit is %f", Fahrenheit);
    return 0;
}
```

Second code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    float Celsius;
    
    printf("temperature in Celsius?\n");
    scanf("%f", &Celsius);
    
    float Fahrenheit = (Celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
    
    printf("temperature in Fahrenheit is %f", Fahrenheit);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to convert celsius to Fahrenheit, but the problem is if I put celsius=37:

First code shows `98.00000` (which is a wrong answer) while the second code shows `98.599998` (which is correct).

Answer (score 3):

When `Celsius` is declared of type `int`, this this expression

```
(Celsius * 9/5) + 32;
```

that doesn't involve any floating point variables is computed entirely in integer space.  Integer division in code basically means "drop the remainder". (e.g. `9/5 == 1`)

Easy fix is to force at least one variable or constant in that expression to be a floating point type.

```
float Fahrenheit  = (Celsius * 9.0f/5) + 32;
```

Or just simply:

```
float Fahrenheit  = (Celsius * 1.8f) + 32;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Celsius` is defined as an `int` (as in the first program), the expression `(Celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;` is computed using integer arithmetics, hence the division by `5` is rounded toward `0`.  Making `Celcius` a `float` allows for entry of decimal values such as `19.5` and performs the computation using floating point arithmetics, giving the expected result, which should really be `98.6`, but shows as `98.599998` because of the limited precision of type `float` and the default number of decimals (6).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    double Celsius;
    
    printf("temperature in Celsius?\n");
    if (scanf("%lf", &Celsius) == 1) {
        double Fahrenheit = (Celsius * 9.0 / 5) + 32;
    
        printf("temperature in Fahrenheit is %g\n", Fahrenheit);
    }
    return 0;
}
```